# configure jenkins to use SSH connection to access remote github repository

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I created a job in Jenkins, in configuration part, I selected "Git" in "Source Code Management" section. Now, my question is, what are the steps to configure my jenkins to use SSH connection to access my github repository instead of using HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a Detailed Instructions on how to set up Jenkins to build GitHub projects

> https://gist.github.com/misterbrownlee/3708738